# How to specify a default migration output dir in typemor?

Tags: npm, typeorm

I use this script to generate a migration

```
"migration:generate": "npm run typeorm -- migration:generate -d ormconfig.ts"
```

This is the ormconfig.ts

```
import { DataSource } from "typeorm";

const AppDataSource = new DataSource({
    type: 'postgres',
    url: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
    synchronize: false,
    logging: true,
    "entities": [
        "src/**/*.entity.ts"
    ],
    "migrations": [
         "src/database/migrations/*.ts"
    ]
  });
  
  export default AppDataSource;
```

The problem is that every time that I want to generate a migration I have to specify the full output path, like this

```
npm run migration:generate ./src/database/migrations/location
```

I would just like to specify the name of the migration, something like this

```
npm run migration:generate location
```